# Quick way to implement simultaneous iterations/folding in Python

Tags: python

I know that the handy `map` and `zip` of Python can iterate through several lists simultaneously; with `zip`, we can get the `i-th` element of all the list parameters in the loop. But I'm wondering if Python has other handy functions for more complexe cases.

For example, the following program simulates a scenario where we have an initial value, and iterate over 2 lists together. It is like a bank account with credits and debits.

```
a0 = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
a1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
init = 100

def f(x, e0, e1):
    return x + e0 - e1

def myIterFold(f, init, a0, a1):
    e_0 = f(init, a0[0], a1[0])
    result = [e_0]
    for i in range(1, len(a0)):
        e_i = f(result[i-1], a0[i], a1[i])
        result.append(e_i)
    return result

print(myIterFold(f, init, a0, a1)) # [105, 110, 115, 120, 125]
```

The above code uses an index loop to 1) achieve a kind of **folding**, 2) and return a **list** including intermediate results (rather than just the final one). Does anyone know if Python has any quick functions or ways to rewrite this code?

PS: I ask this question, because I want to see how Python could achieve/simulate this task which is a common and easy pattern in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you want in words, so people who don't know OCaml can answer?

Comment: @user2357112 I just replaced the OCaml code by Python code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for this, but my guess is you can use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

a0 = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
a1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
e = 100

lst = [e] + [x - y for x, y in zip(a0, a1)]
print(list(accumulate(lst))[1:])

# [105, 110, 115, 120, 125]
```

Comment: Thank you... `accumulate` is good in this case, but what if my function is `def f(x, e0, e1): return x * e0 / e1`?

Comment: Let's just use `def f(x, e0, e1): return x * e0 / e1` instead of `def f(x, e0, e1): return x + e0 - e1` in my code, though the former does not have an obvious concrete meaning.

Comment: So from the above example, it should output 100*6, 100*6*6, 100*6*6*6, ... ?

Comment: Yes, `[600, 3600, 21600, ...]`.

Comment: Your code is good enough and because you used a function `f()`, you could change it to apply any operation. There is no quick function in Python to do that. `accumulate` just comes handy for addition.